# frequency distribution of vectors

Tags: r, frequency-distribution

I have a list of vectors in R (permutations of `{1,2,3}`) like this:

```
> Ls
$L
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3


$L
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3


$L
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    1    3
```

I would like to have a frequency distribution *of these vectors*, i.e. the desired result should look like: `123 -> 2` and `213 -> 1`.

Obviously "`Table`" cannot do the job. I thought about using a unique identifier for each permutation (eg: hashcoding?) but this would make the original objects unrecognizable. Someone can help?

Answer (score 2):

```
table(do.call(paste0, do.call(rbind.data.frame, Ls)))
```

Comment: @ChiPak Yes. rbind.data.frame(Ls) is different.

Answer (score 1):

`table` can do the job~

```
B=unlist(lapply(LS, paste, collapse = "_"))
table(B)

B
1_2_3 2_3_1 
    2     1
```